# preencher arraylist com informações de atributo arraylist de outra classe

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, swing, arraylist

tenho uma classe Evento com um atributo  `arraylist<string>lista`. Preencho esse atributo em um JFrame TelaLista e utilizo um  `evento.setLista("informaçao");` para adicionar a string do textField no arraylist da classe Evento. Gostaria de saber como posso utilizar essa informação que foi salva pelo set em outra classe. Tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
        ArrayList<String> st = new ArrayList();   
        Evento ev = new Evento();
        st = ev.getLista();
        
      for (int i = 0; i < st.size(); i++) {         
            System.out.println("teste" + st.get(i) );
        } 
    }
```

mas esse array st fica vazio...

O JFrame que comentei que está preenchendo com o setLista está dessa forma:

```
Evento listaTipo = new Evento();
listaTipo.setLista(textFieldNome.getText());
```

alguem tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer com que o arraylist st da outra classe em questao fique preenchido com as informações que salvei no jframe?

Answer (score 0):

João, claramente a lista virá vazia pois você tem duas instâncias diferentes. Suas instâncias são:

```
Evento ev = new Evento();
```

E a outra instância que você preencheu a lista é essa:

```
Evento listaTipo = new Evento();
```

Para recuperar os valores da listaTipo, você deve utilizar a mesma instância. Ou seja, você deveria fazer algo do tipo:

```
Evento listaTipo = new Evento();
listaTipo.setLista(textFieldNome.getText()); 

ArrayList<String> st = new ArrayList();   
st = listaTipo.getLista();
```